# Debugging MVC2 project in Chrome caching too aggressively

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-2, caching, google-chrome

I'm playing around with MVC2 for the first time and running into some caching issues. Every time I make changes to my javascript pages and debug my site I'm not seeing the latest changes. I know I'm not seeing the latest changes because if I view the source of my page and select to view the javascript file I receive the old version.

What is causing this and how do I ensure I'm always getting the latest version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add time variable to your source file.

```
<script src="../my.js?v=1345485745"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Go into Chromes developer tools, then network tab. Click the wrench in the bottom right.  There is a check box to disable the cache.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer not to change the behaviour of Chrome or change the source, there always is the possibility to refresh the page with Ctrl+F5 or Shift+F5: [reloads your current page, ignoring cached content](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=49e423e184cea8da&hl=en), as most browsers do. Or start an incognito session. Enough options. Whatever suits you best.